# What are the fanner beasts?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, adnd-2e, dark-sun

I'm reading some of the original lore for Dark Sun, and the dray are described as herding "fanner beasts", supposedly some sort of lizard-like creature. But I can't find any information about what these beasts actually look like or what their characteristics and stats are. Can anyone point me to some good sources of information about "fanner beasts"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're cow-sized fat lizards with a single large horn and a large frilled collar that can be extended like a dilophosaurus to make themselves look more threatening. Their name comes from this 'fan' that extends. Their main predator is dragon beetles, foot-long beetles with poison stingers that try to pick off young fanners when carrion is in low supply.

The reason why you haven't found anything is because they haven't updated the underground city of New Giustenal since 1994, when it was published in the AD&D sourcebook 'City by the Silt Sea'.